# Scala macros: Check if symbol/type is Tuple

Tags: scala, scala-macros

In a typed blackbox macro(implicit materializer), how do you check if a `Type` or `Symbol` is a tuple? There's the obvious solution of pattern matching or something like that, but is there an `isTuple` method that I can find anywhere?

So far I know I can do this:

```
def typed[A : c.WeakTypeTag]: Symbol = weakTypeOf[A].typeSymbol

object TupleSymbols {
  val tuple2 = typed[(_, _)]
  val tuple3 = typed[(_, _, _)]
  // ... and so on
}
```

Is there a more sane approach than the above monstrosity?

Comment: Check that name matches `scala.Tuple\d*`?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Is that the best possible? Feels flimsy but doable.

Comment: I certainly would prefer it over defining `tuple2` etc. but I don't know if there are better alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the suggestion in the comments, this can be nicely handled with simple matching.

```
def isTuple(tpe: Type): Boolean = {
  tpe.typeSymbol.fullName.startsWith("scala.Tuple")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  import c.universe._
  import Flag._

  def tuple(i: Int) = {
    def list = (1 to i).toList
    c.typecheck(
      ExistentialTypeTree(
        tq"(..${list map (i => Ident(TypeName(s"_$i")))})", //just like (_,_, ...)
        list map (i =>
          TypeDef(Modifiers(DEFERRED | SYNTHETIC), TypeName(s"_$i"), List(), TypeBoundsTree(EmptyTree, EmptyTree))
          )
      )
    )
  }
```

//test

```
println(tuple(2).tpe <:< typeOf[(_, _)])//true 
println(tuple(3).tpe <:< typeOf[(_, _, _)])//true
```

edit1 :

```
def asTuple(tpe: Type): Boolean = {
  def allTuple = 1 to 22 map { i =>
    val typeNames = 1 to i map (e => TypeName(s"_$e"))
    tq"(..$typeNames) forSome {..${typeNames.map(e => q"type $e")} }"
  } map (t => c.typecheck(t).tpe)

  allTuple.exists(_ <:< tpe)
}
```

//test

```
println(asTuple(typeOf[Int])) // false 
println(asTuple(typeOf[(_, _)])) // true 
println(asTuple(typeOf[(_, _,_)])) // true
```

Comment: Thank you but I wasn't looking to construct tuple types, or use the AST, quasiquotes are easier. I'm not sure you understood my question, I'm looking to check if an arbitrary type is a tuple without manually defining all the tuple types.